# Cloudflare page with custom domain is cached after deploy

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

We have a cloudflare page with custom domain, eg.:

1. Page: xxxxxx-frontend-about.pages.dev
2. Custom domain about.xxxxxxxx.co

We deployed a new version and we could se that the (1) was updated, but (2) was not and we could see `age: 6456`.

I guess it is not intentional and the cache for the page should be purged after deployment?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your custom domain, which has a CNAME record pointing to the cloudflare page is proxied. This is slightly redundant, as Cloudflare already handles DDOS protection and caching at the page level. This is only needed, if you want to customize the protection settings.

**To fix this**, you have to go into your Cloudflare's DNS section, click edit on the record pointing to your cloudflare page amd switch the Proxy status option from 'Proxied' to 'DNS only'.

This means the website will bypass the cache of your custom domain, and will always show the newest page.

*Alternatively,* if you need the custom protection settings, you can purge cache on your proxied domain after each deploy.

Comment: Thanks. That helped! CF enables Proxy by default when custom domain is added.